# Both `TouchBehavior.CommandParameter` and `TouchBehavior.LongPressCommandParameter` are always passed as `null` to `Command` and `LongPressCommand`

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Both `TouchBehavior.CommandParameter` and `TouchBehavior.LongPressCommandParameter` are always passed as `null` to `Command` and `LongPressCommand`.

In the following example, when an item in the `CollectionView` is tapped, the resulting alert will always display `Selected value:` because the CommandParameter is always `null`. It should say `Selected vale: Item 1`, for example, when the user taps `Item 1`.

[image]

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0"
                     Spacing="25">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
           Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
           SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

    <Label Text="Tapping or long pressing an item does not correctly pass that item as CommandParameter or LongTouchCommandParameter."
           Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
           SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"  />

    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
                <Label Padding="10"
                       Text="{Binding .}"
                       x:Name="Label">
                    <Label.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:TouchBehavior Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.ShowItemCommand}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                               LongPressCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.ShowItemCommand}"
                                               LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                        <!--
                        CommandParameter and LongPressCommandParameter are always passed as null in the CommunityToolkit.Maui TouchBehavior.
                        this was not the case with https://github.com/Axemasta/Maui.TouchEffect -->
                    </Label.Behaviors>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string Title => "Hello, Maui!";

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];

    /// <summary>
    /// item is always null. This was not the case in https://github.com/Axemasta/Maui.TouchEffect
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [RelayCommand]
    private Task ShowItem(string item) => Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert($"Selected value:", item, "OK");
}
```

#### Sample Reproduction

Here is a link to a reproduction sample  for this bug: https://github.com/hansmbakker/bugrepro-communitytoolkit-maui-touchbehavior-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

In .NET MAUI, you are required to manually set the `BindingContext` for every `Behavior`. In other words, Behaviors do not inherit the `BindingContext` of the `VisualElement` to which they are attached.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors?view=net-maui-8.0#create-a-net-maui-behavior

[image]

### Updated Code

Here is the updated XAML to get your code working. It uses a view-to-view binding to bind `TouchBehavior.BindingContext` to `Label.BindingContext`:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0"
                     Spacing="25">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
           Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
           SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

    <Label Text="Tapping or long pressing an item does not correctly pass that item as CommandParameter or LongTouchCommandParameter."
           Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
           SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"  />

    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
                <Label Padding="10"
                       Text="{Binding .}"
                       x:Name="label">
                    <Label.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:TouchBehavior Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.ShowItemCommand}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                               LongPressCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.ShowItemCommand}"
                                               LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                               BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference label}, Path=BindingContext}"/>
                    </Label.Behaviors>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

A bit unrelated to the Behavior BindingContext problem, here is my recommendation for small performance improvement to your ViewModel (both `Title` and `Items` can be read-only properties):

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string Title { get; } = "Hello, Maui!";

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];

    [RelayCommand]
    private Task ShowItem(string item) => Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert($"Selected value:", item, "OK");
}
```

#### Screenshot of Updated App

Here is a screen shot of your app working as expected after updating the code:

[image]

#### .NET MAUI Community Toolkit Unit Tests

Here are the Unit Tests I wrote for the `TouchBehavior` in `CommunityToolkit.Maui` where we verify the `LongPressCommand` does indeed pass in `LongPressCommandParameter`;

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/51dc63a7642370849e413d87072b668fa022e303/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.UnitTests/Behaviors/TouchBehaviorTests.cs#L612-L674

And here are the Unit Tests I wrote for the `TouchBehavior` in `CommunityToolkit.Maui` where we verify the `Command` does indeed pass in `CommandParameter`;

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/51dc63a7642370849e413d87072b668fa022e303/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.UnitTests/Behaviors/TouchBehaviorTests.cs#L550-L610